# Does a Legendary Card obtained as an arena reward resets the 'Pity Timer'?

Tags: hearthstone

It's a widely accepted idea that there is a 'pity timer' when opening card packs in Hearthstone, meaning that after X number of packs opened without a Legendary card, your next pack will always contain (at least) 1.

After a recent 12 wins run (Yay!) My reward contained 1 pack, a bunch of gold and a Legendary card.  At that point I thought maybe I hit my pity timer, as it had been a lot of opened packs since my last Legendary.

Does a Legendary Card obtained as an arena reward resets the 'Pity Timer'?

Comment: I'm not sure, but since the pity timers are bound to a specific set (Classic, GVG, TGT, ... all have a seperate one), I would assume it doesn't. After all, which one would it use/reset? The legendary arena reward can be any legendary from any set.

Comment: makes sense, but maybe the steps to get your card are
`-determine which set at random
-look at pity counter
-output card`

Comment: I think it just rolls a random card honestly. I'm not even sure it rolls for rarity first. It might simply select any card at equal probability. The card drop is so rare there's not much relevant data to go from anyway, so I don't think we can know for sure unless someone makes Brode tweet it.

Comment: you're probably right.  Let's hope someone needs rep points desperately enough to fill Brode's twitter

Answer (score 13):

Legendary Cards acquired from Arena rewards do not reset the "pity timer". This is because the pity timer is only a concept that applies to Legendary Cards acquired through pack openings. As Arena rewards do not fall within that category, no pity timer is effected.

Similarly, the free Legendary Card that you get from the Welcome Bundle does not reset the pity timer.

It is also interesting to note that the pity timer counts independently for each type of card pack. Thus getting a Legendary Card in the newest "Mean Streets of Gadgetzan" card pack will not reset the pity timer for getting a Legendary Card in a Classic pack. [Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/hearthstone/comments/3z7jyh/pity_timer_on_packs_opening_and_the_best_strategy/)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard of Arena rewards being on a pity timer - I believe they are completely random.

What I had read about the Welcome bundle was that the bundle Lengendary had no effect on chance to get a Lengendary from packs.  It's a safe assumption that the same rule holds for Arena Legendaries.